# Comments on Patankar's book Numerical heat transfer and fluid flow

Tags: fluid-mechanics, heat-transfer, simulation

How to make comments on the book of Patankar, titled 'f' in 1980? Is it really worthy for beginners in the field of numerical heat transfer to read it?
Besides, after finishing reading this book, what else learning materials should I review if I want to conduct a good simulation in duct convective heat transfer?

Comment: Is there an error in your question? Is the title of the book really *f*?

Answer (score 0):

Read the material for the simulation package you are using, also check to see if there are other relevant books: Simonson Heat Transfer may be worth a look - at least I found it very useful and it is still in my personal library.

Can’t comment on Patankar...

Comment: haha, I got it. Thank you very much!